# how to check whether the ajax request handled by a specific url or not prototype

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento, prototype

I try to use an ajax request to save a category option and wonder how could I detect whether my ajax request has been successfully handled by ajax_attributes.phtml. My issue is no matter what url I specify, it always alerts it works, even I change the url into something `like yadayada.phtml`,which is not existed at all.

```
 new Ajax.Request('ajax_attributes.phtml', 
            {
                parameters: {categoryId: categoryId},
                onSuccess: function(response) {
                // Handle the response content...
                alert('it works');
                },

                onFailure: function(){
                 alert('Something went wrong...');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

```
var request = $.ajax({
     url: "script.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { categoryId: categoryId},  
     dataType: "html"
}); 

request.done(function( msg ) {
     alert('it work');
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {  
     alert('Something went wrong...');
});
```

Comment: Is that jquery? I need prototype instead

Comment: Arf yes sorry it's jQuery i always use it i find it's better.